# Specifying baseline in internal coordinates with graphicx package

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, baseline

I'm using the `graphicx` package. By default, included graphics are aligned with the baseline at the bottom of the image. I know how to make images vertically centered (using `\vcenter`) or top-aligned. But what I really want is to just use the origin of the included figure as the baseline. Is there any way to do this conveniently, using either `graphicx` or some other similar package?

Comment: By "origin" you probably mean the vertical and horizontal midpoint/centre of the image, correct? Or, ultimately, only the vertical midpoint, since the image will be set to the right of wherever you place the `\includegraphics` macro.

Comment: @Werner, no, I mean the origin in the internal coordinates of the image. I create my figures in MetaPost, so I put my origin exactly where I want it.

Comment: [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) places the image as a box, as defined by the bounding box, and may not consider the origin of the actual image.

Comment: @Werner, yes, that's its behaviour. I want different behaviour; is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you create the image within your document (rather than importing it from an external source). But, I don't really know...

Comment: If you are making an EPS file in metapost and including it then not really possible, if you are using the feature of the pdftex  driver file for graphicx to directly include mp code, translating to pdf via context based tex macros, them it's probably possible but you'd need to provide a complete test example in your question.

Comment: Thanks, David! I didn't know about an option for directly including mp code, I will investigate.

Comment: There may be some confusion as to exactly what I'm asking for. EPS files have a bounding box at the top of the file, which gives not just the dimensions of the figure but also an offset (which you can think of as a preferred origin). I'd like the point (0,0) with respect to those bounding coordinates to end up on the TeX baseline.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done when including image files with `\includegraphics`: `graphicx` has no interface to whatever the code was that originally produced the figure.

However, it can be done if you integrate your graphics drawing with the TeX code itself. I don't know much MP, but here is an example with another drawing package.

This shows a Ti*k*Z/`pgf` solution, using the `baseline` key to specify a point in the diagram (named coordinate or arbitrary *x*-*y* coordinate pair) for baseline alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\mytest{\node[draw] (A) {text};}

\begin{document}
Here is base-aligned
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
  \mytest
\end{tikzpicture}
and here is top-aligned
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.north)]
  \mytest
\end{tikzpicture}.

And here is a pair of axes with the origin on the baseline:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},x=1em,y=1em,font=\footnotesize]
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,1) node[right] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}.
\end{document}
```

[image]